# Python Session and Cookies

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, python-requests, data-persistence

Hello dear Stack users,

I am trying to login to a webservice via json exchange and trying to implement the auth mechanism as you can see [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/)

```
import requests
class Testauth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    """Implements a custom authentication scheme."""

    def __init__(self, email, passwd):
        loginjson = {"Data":{"EMAIL":email,"PASSWORD":passwd}}
        req = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', json=loginjson)
        self.token = self.token = req.json()['data'] #orig service has : ['Data'][0]['SESSION_ID']

    def __call__(self, r):
        """Attach an API token to a custom auth header."""
        r.prepare_cookies({'SESSION_ID' : f'{self.token}'})  # Python 3.6+
        return r

curSession = requests.Session() 
curSession.auth=Testauth('email','pass')
page = curSession.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
print(curSession.cookies)
print(page.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

My expectation was that since it did authentication while accessing the /get (with the auth method) curSession  should contain cookies

But checking cursession.cookies shows none, only the request contains cookies.

[Here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) shows that session should persist cookies between requests but it does not, where am I doing wrong in here

> Tl;Dr:
>
> When using sessions, implementing custom auth doesnt persist cookie in
> auth, gets new auth cookie everytime